# sharepoint remoted event receiver event for folder added

Tags: sharepoint-online, remote-event-receiver

sharepoint remote event receivers itemAdded event not fire when adding folder to a documentlibrary. how to get event fire when folder is created in sharepoint?

Comment: Is it being fired when any file is uploaded?

Comment: yes, when file added itemAdded is fires.